# Call API at Exit?

Tags: go

I'm using an API that has a 'bind' function that I call at the start of my program, but to be a good API user, I need to call the 'unbind' function when my program quits for any reason.  Is there a way to do that?  I can't find anything on Google, and `defer api.Unbind()` doesn't seem to get called.  Thx.

Comment: There is not a general way to run code on any exit from the program.  The best option is to run the call on "normal" exit from the program: (A) always exit the program by returning from main (don't call os.Exit).  (B) add `defer api.Unbind()` to main().

Comment: If `defer api.Unbind()` isn't being called, how are you exiting main? `log.Fatal`? `os.Exit`? Signals?

Comment: @JimB:  There are several log.Fatal() spots that could happen....I guess I need to go back and do the api.Unbind right before the log.Fatal() calls.

Comment: Or don't call `log.Fatal` if you need to cleanup on exit. You probably want to add signal handlers too if you're trying to make this more robust, though you of course cannot catch SIGKILL, so there is only so much you can do.

Answer (score 1):

There is no single way to get a 100% guarantee that some code is called before abnormal program termination. The closest you can get is to react to `os.Interrupt` (and also `syscall.SIGTERM` on Unix systems) and make sure your cleanup is done thereafter. A good way to achieve this is to use [NotifyContext](https://pkg.go.dev/os/signal#NotifyContext) because it ties in nicely with the [context package](https://pkg.go.dev/context) the main use of which is to allow for implementing cancellation of (potentially) long-running code.